# Returning httpresponse with queryset for ListView after post in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a listview with formmixin after submitting the form I was trying to return the exact same view with some extra messages, but I havent been able to return the query set, hence the list is not appearing,
Can anyone pls help me.

**Views.py**

```
class NewsletterList(FormMixin, generic.ListView):
    queryset = newsletter.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
    template_name = 'newsletterlist.html'
    form_class = SubscriberForm


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SubscriberForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            sub = Subscriber(email=request.POST['email'], conf_num=random_digits())
            sub.save()
            
            return render(request, 'newsletterlist.html', {'form': SubscriberForm()})

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) 
    context['newsletter_list'] = newsletter.objects.filter(status = 1) 
    return context
```

*HTML*

```
 {% for newsletter in newsletter_list %}
      

      <a href="{{newsletter.slug}}" class="d-flex justify-content-between list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <span class=""><b>{{ newsletter.title }}</b> - {{newsletter.catchy_line|slice:":200" }}</span>. 
        <span class="">{{ newsletter.datepublished}}</span> 
      </a>
    

 
    {% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try
queryset = Newsletter.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('-created_on')
spelling problem

Comment: HI Thanks for your comment, query set is working fine initially, after the post once the form is submitted I need to render the same page with an extra message, the return is not working

Comment: I currently used redirect to same url, but I cant pass parameters along with redirect

Comment: try that: def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['newsletter'] = Newsletter.objects.filter (status = 1) 
        return context

Comment: The list is not still showing, I have updated my view and html code above, can you pls have a look

Comment: Thank you  the issue is solved, I used a wrong name in context